# Starting "Click-Once" published application keeps trying to install .NET Framework

Tags: .net, windows-vista, clickonce, installation, cycle

The following dialog window keeps popping on my computrer when starting "Click-Once" published application from Internet URL:

> [Microsoft .NET Framework Setup]
>   - Would you like to download and install the Microsoft .NET Framework?
>
> The content you are trying to access
>   requires the Microsoft .NET Framework.
>   Would you like to download and install
>   this from Microsoft Download Center
>   Now?
>
> ....

"Click-Once" worked OK in the past without trying to install .NET Framework but after (I guess) my MS Windows Vista Ultimate System got installed the following automatic updates:

> Update for Windows (KB936448 - .Net
>   Framework 3.0 RTM x86 ru-RU)
>
> Update for Windows (KB936403 - .Net
>   Framework 2.0 RTM x86 ru-RU)

"Click-Once" stopped to work trying to install .NET Framework every time, and even if I run this install it keeps trying to install .NET Framework on subsequent "Click-Once" activations...

I have removed the above updates from my system, and I have installed .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 - but I'm still getting the same issue.

I'd expect it should be possible to manually patch some System Registry Entries to fix this issue but I do not know which ones.

Please advise how this issue can be solved.

P.S. FYI: Windows Vista SP1 *is not* installed on my system

Comment: I suppose you're doing that with IE... Which version of IE is that? 7? 8? beta?

Comment: is the link to the application an .html file or a .application file?  what's your user agent (http://whatsmyuseragent.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too for a while.

It was caused when I opened a .application file in notepade and set notepad to be the default handler for .application files.  (It needs to be the ClickOnce client runtime component).

Resetting this back to the default handler corrected the problem

Comment: Thank you, Robert. Yes, I have had .application file once opened in Notepad and it(Notepad) seems to have been assigned as default program. I have just set "Application Deployment Support Library" as deafult program for .application file, and click-once works well on my Vista PC now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the locale is the reason? You have runtime for ru-RU, what is locale of the ClickOnce application?

Comment: Thank you for reply: I must say I do not know how to define (target) locale for ClickOnce setup - before I have got automatically installed mentioned in my first message updates I used to use this computer with ru-Ru locale to make well-working Click-Once setups, which worked OK for PCs from US, Canada, Sweden...



Basically my question is about procedure Click-Once uses during app setup: what Registry Entries/GAC Assemblies/other installed files it looks for using ClickOnce prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

> [Microsoft .NET Framework Setup] - Would you like to download and install the Microsoft .NET Framework?

Does it state what version of the Framework is required for the application?

Did you write the application yourself? Perhaps there is something inside the Visual Studio Project Properties. Under **Publish** > **Prerequisites** there is the list of prerequisites that the application will attempt to install (if told to do so). Is the version of .NET Framework listed there?